# JavaScript - this of this

Tags: javascript, oop

```
String.prototype.foo = {};
String.prototype.foo.bar = function() {
    //How can you reference the "grandparent" string?
    console.log(this.parent.parent); //obviously, doesn't exist
}
```

As in, `"Hello, Nurse!".foo.bar()` would log "Hello, Nurse!".

Will it make a difference if there's control over foo?

Edit: There, foo is defined.

Edit2: Fine, instead of `this.this.this`, `this.parent.parent`. Of course parent doesn't exist, but hopefully now the semantics won't get in the way.

Edit3: There isn't a specific case. The provided details are pretty much all I got: There's an object foo, part of a prototype. `foo.bar` is a method of `foo`, and is supposed to access its grandparent. That's it. Nothing else. That's all the information I have.

Edit4: Resolved. Based on the answer provided (and some second-hand help from Douglas Crockford):

```
String.prototype.foo = function() {
    var that = this;
    return {
        bar : function() {
            console.log(that.valueOf());
        }
    }
}
//Called:
"Hello, Nurse!".foo().bar();
```

Comment: For the same effect, this.this.this doesn't work.

Comment: `this` is _still_ self, not parent.

Comment: Edited, adding another .this. Happy?

Comment: It'll be easier to answer if we understand what you're trying to do. With that code right there, it won't work because String.prototype.foo is undefined. What is foo? Are you trying to inherit from something?

Comment: @Zirak: It doesn't matter how many `this`s you add. Self's self is still self. `/root/././././.` is still `/root`. I suspect you'll have to pass the object reference to `foo` whenever you create it.

Comment: It doesn't matter what foo is, hence using foo. It might be something added with MooTools or an existing property. But the point is versed; getting the grandparent.

Comment: @Zirak: No, the point is, it _does_ matter what `foo` is. Post it.

Comment: It does matter what foo is. There has to be something there or you can't set the property bar.

Comment: @Tomalak - this.this is what I used lacking any other meaning.

Comment: @Zirak: I once went into a shop in a foreign country, not knowing the word for "tomatoes". So I just shrugged and asked for strawberries instead, expecting the shopkeeper to know what I meant. It didn't really work.

Comment: @Robert - Added it in. @Tomalak - It _doesn't matter_. I used this lacking anything else to treat as the parent of a parent; if that existed, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @Zirak: I'm not understanding the point of the foo.

Comment: @Tomalak - edited, semantics don't matter. @Robert - it's an object. As said, this was meant to be generic.

Comment: @Zirak: If you know what is and isn't relevant here, then you should be able to answer the question yourself, eh? :)

Comment: @Zirak: I know what it is, I don't know why it is. Tell me what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: @Tomalak and @Rober - I do know that whatever foo does, I want to get the grandparent. For argument's sake, let's say that foo is a function that does things to the string, and bar is always a method in foo.

Comment: @Zirak: I wanted to see a full, proper testcase so that I could tell you precisely what to add in order to make this work. But I've kind of lost interest now :(

Comment: By the way, this is not always self, it's the context of execution of  a function. If you call a function using call and apply you can set it to anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way this can be done, is to turn `foo()` into a function. Think of it as initialising the `foo` namespace for a particular string:

```
String.prototype.foo = function () {
    var str = String(this);
    var o = Object(this)
    o.bar = function () {
         console.log(str);
    };
    return o;
};
```

Then you can use:

```
"foobar".foo().bar(); // logs "foobar"
```

Or if we rename `foo` and `bar` into something more exciting:

```
"Hello!".console().log(); // logs "Hello!"
```

---

#### Why is it so complicated?

Each function is called with a particular **context** that is a single object. Whether it is called with `a.b()` or `a.b.c.d()` doesn't matter - it is given the object immediately to the **left** of the function call as its context. So the context for `a.b()` would be `a`, and the context for `a.b.c.d()` is `c`. The keyword `this` references the context. Because `c` is just an **object** (not a running function) it has no context, and it has no concept of `this`, so `this.this` makes no sense.

Therefore, it is not possible to generically access the so-called "parent". Juan's answer gives a good conceptual explanation why. However, if what you want to achieve is namespacing in prototype functions, then you *can* do this by returning an augmented object from `foo`.

Notice I also had to convert `this` into an `Object` above. This is because you can't attach properties to primitive values like strings. `var str = "foo"; str.bar = 1` will work, but only because JS automatically converts `"foo"` into an object. However, since `str` references the primitive, not the automatically created object, the object is then immediately discarded, and we lose `bar`.

Comment: How does this let you access the *parent* object in a generic way?

Comment: @Juan, the `str` is the so-called *parent* object in this case.

Comment: Well, it's hardcoded, anybody can do that, you may as well just use `String` directly!

Comment: @Box9: I obviously already looked at the example! Couldn't make sense of it except in the way I told you. Please explain how this can be used to generically access the parent of an object.

Comment: @Juan I never claimed to generically access the parent of an object. Maybe I'll add in a statement there to look at your answer, cos I'm not disputing it! I'm just trying to solve the problem of namespacing functions on a prototype.

Comment: Thank you very much. At the end, I used a slightly different version of basically the code you provided. See my edited question for it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for an object to know what object it's a property of. The same object (in your case a function) could be attached to multiple objects. Here's an example:

```
var myObj = {};
var objA = {prop: myObj};
var objB = {nother: myObj}
```

If given a reference to myObj, how could you possibly know which parent object you're referring to? In one case, it's nothing, another case, it's objA, the last case, it's a 'child' object of objB. If you explain why you'd like this behavior, we can help you solve the problem at hand. But the answer to the question is that you **CAN'T** do it.

Comment: Would it help to know that `foo` is always a method of `String`, and that `bar` is always a method of `foo`?

Comment: The point is that you can't know. Anyone could always do `var b = String.prototype.foo.bar`. That's the nature of this dynamic language.

Comment: Of course, your way also works if I do `Object.toString = "hi".toLowerCase`. But it'll bug out, so I'm assuming best-case.