# Add function to constructor prototype with method with access to this from constructor instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like the desired result as per the comments in the code below:

```
// constructor
function As(data) {
  this.data = data
}

function helloWorld() {
  console.log(this.data)
}

helloWorld.myMethod = {
  // ...do sideffect
  // desired: execute helloWorld here bound against `asI` 
}

As.prototype.helloWorld = helloWorld


const asI = new As('some data')
asI.helloWorld() // => 'some data'

// desired
asI.helloWorld.myMethod() // desired result: => 'some data'
```

Edit: This not a duplicate of [JavaScript - this of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751058/javascript-this-of-this) as I thought, as evidenced by the solutions below.

Comment: Sorry, just updated... that made no sense a moment ago.

Comment: Why do you need this function to be in prototype not in instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - this of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751058/javascript-this-of-this)

Comment: @xianshenglu not in the end :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need this property to be in prototype you could use custom property getter.

```js
// constructor
function As(data) {
  this.data = data
}


Object.defineProperty(As.prototype, 'helloWorld', {
  get: function() {
    function helloWorld() {
      console.log(this.data)
    }
    
    helloWorld.myMethod = (function(){
      console.log(this.data)
    }).bind(this);
    
    return helloWorld;
  }
});



const asI = new As('some data')
asI.helloWorld() // => 'some data'

// desired
asI.helloWorld.myMethod() // desired result: => 'some data'
```

Keep in mind that this naive implementation will create new functions every time you access `helloWorld`.

Comment: You lead me to the answer (thank you!!!), but you'll have to answer the following/update your answer before I can accept your answer: why the binding? Setting `const data = this.data` at the beginning of the get function and then `console.log(data)` was sufficient in my case (and avoids the function creation). Does this lose some behaviour compared to your answer?

Comment: @Dan For the specific use case capturing `this.data` in closure would suffice. But this still creates 2 functions for every access. The better option would be to create `helloWorld` property in constructor per instance.

Comment: Ok, so in my use case I either have to loop a list of (all standard) valid dom elements adding these defineProperties to the prototype, or adding bound functions every time it is instantiated. I think choosing between defining two functions per access vs 70+ functions per instantiation is my scenario, so this defineProperty method is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a getter along with [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
// constructor
function As(data) {
  this.data = data
}

function helloWorld() {
  console.log(this.data)
}

Object.defineProperty(As.prototype, 'helloWorld', {
  get() {
    return Object.assign(helloWorld, {
      myMethod: () => {
        console.log(this.data)
      },
    })
  },
})

const asI = new As('some data')
asI.helloWorld() // => 'some data'

asI.helloWorld.myMethod() // => 'some data'
```

Comment: Correction, this probably made the final answer much more performant, thank you!

Comment: `Object.assign` actually mutates its first argument. So you might get incorrect context if you save `helloWorld` in a variable.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko good you mentioned that explicitly. A corollary of the fact this is undesired is that you can memoize the binding of myMethod.